# How do I fix OpenSSL Error "libssl.so.10, needed by lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1" when Compiling PHP on CentOS 7?

Tags: gcc, openssl, centos7, linker-errors

I'm starting out with a completely clean install of CentOS 7 with nothing installed.

Starting out, I have `yum install`ed these RPM's:

- make
- mlocate
- pcre-devel
- expat-devel
- epel-release
- libxml2-devel
- yum-utils
- wget
- vim
- lynx
- libnghttp2-devel
- libnghttp2
- nghttp2
- libpng-devel
- gcc*
- perl-Module-Load-Conditional
- perl-core
- curl-devel
- openssl-devel
- mariadb-devel
- unixODBC-devel
- bzip2-devel
- libjpeg-devel
- libXpm-devel
- freetype-devel
- gmp-devel
- libmcrypt-devel
- httpd-devel

** RESOLUTION EDIT **
Added the following RPMS:

- cyrus-sasl
- cyrus-sasl-devel

I have Compiled OpenSSL 1.1.1, cURL 7.62.0, and HTTPD 2.4.38 from source with the respective commands below:

## OpenSSL

```
$ ./config \
  --prefix=/opt/openssl \
  -Wl,-rpath=/opt/openssl/bin \
  --openssldir=/opt/openssl \
  shared \
  zlib
$ make clean
$ make
$ make install
```

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

## cURL

```
$ env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure \
  --prefix=/opt/curl \
  --with-ssl \
  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/lib"
  CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/openssl/include -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/include"
make clean
make
make install
```

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.62.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.62.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.7 nghttp2/1.31.1
Release-Date: 2018-10-31
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

## HTTPD

```
$ env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure \
  --prefix=/opt/httpd \
  --with-included-apr \
  --enable-so \
  --with-port=80 \
  --enable-http2 \
  --enable-ssl \
  --enable-ssl=shared \
  --with-ssl=/opt/openssl \
  --with-curl=/opt/curl \
  LDFLAG="-L/opt/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/lib -L/opt/curl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/curl/lib" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/openssl/include -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/include -I/opt/curl/include -Wl,-rpath,/opt/curl/include"
$ make clean
$ make
$ make install
```

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 13 2019 15:14:01
```

Everything works fine up to this point. I am able to load an HTML page through a browser on a remote machine. (after opening port 80)

Here is where I start running into problems.

** OPENLDAP EDIT (RESOLVED BY COMPILING OPEN LDAP) **

```
$ env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure \
  --prefix=/opt/openldap \
  --with-tls \
  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/lib" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/openssl/include -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/include"
$ make clean
$ make depend
$ make
$ make install
```

## PHP

```
$ env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure \
  --with-apxs2=/opt/httpd/bin/apxs \
  --prefix=/opt/php \
  --with-mysqli \
  --with-pdo-mysql \
  --enable-pdo \
  --enable-ftp \
  --with-zlib \
  --enable-zip \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-curl=/opt/curl \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl  \
  --enable-exif \
  --with-gd \
  --enable-shared \
  --enable-cgi \
  --with-ldap=/opt/openldap \
  LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/opt/openldap/lib -L/opt/openldap/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/lib -L/opt/openssl/lib" \
  CPPFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,/opt/openldap/include -I/opt/openldap/include -Wl,-rpath,/opt/openssl/include -I/opt/openssl/include"
$ make clean
$ make
$ make install
```

### Make Error

Upon running `make clean;make` I am presented with this error:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
  /usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
  /usr/bin/ld: ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SSLv3_server_method@@libssl.so.10'
  //usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

### Make Test Log

The `make test` command returns the same errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libldap.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/usr/bin/ld: ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SSLv3_server_method@@libssl.so.10'
//usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop this warning use the systems SSL-Library and do not compile it yourself.

Or you must build all libraries, you are using, which link against OpenSSL, yourself (In your case libldap)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I'm going to update the original question with the working configure scripts, including configuring and installing the OpenLDAP library.

In order to use the most up-to-date version of OpenSSL, I had to compile OpenLDAP with the most recent version of the compiled OpenSSL.